# Can anyone help me with manipulating the projection matrices?

Tags: correlation, econometrics, r-squared, projection

I am trying to prove the below equality to prove that the squared correlation of coefficient is equal to r-square(i.e. $r^2 = R^2$): $$Y'M_\iota \hat{Y} = \hat{Y}'M_\iota \hat{Y}$$ where $\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta}$ and $M_\iota = I - \iota(\iota'\iota)^{-1}\iota'$, and $\iota = \text{vector of 1}$. The below is what I could get:
$$ Y'M_\iota \hat{Y} = (M_\iota Y)'M_\iota \hat{Y} = (M_\iota X\beta + M_\iota u)'M_\iota \hat{Y}$$
From here, I am not sure how I can proceed to prove that the above equality holds.. Could anyone please give me a hint to the proper way to prove this? Thank you!

Comment: Try, instead, writing $Y = X\hat{\beta} + \epsilon$ and substituting in the first equation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would $M_\iota$$\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is residual, become zero?

Comment: What is $\hat{Y}^T\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the vector of errors from the regression (i.e., not the true innovations)?  If you expand $M$ you'll see that is one of the terms making up the l.h.s. of your first equation... that should get you farther.